# Remove any duplicate value in a specific row by comparing specific column in two dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have two Pandas dataframes (Python3). It will look like below.

```
df1
name, score
Tom, 130
Jane, 98
Anny, 81
Chuck, 92

df2
name
Amy
Chuck
Dave
Danny
Emma
Jack
Tom
Taro
```

What I want to do is to look at df1 and if any name found in df2, remove name, score row from df1 altogether.

I searched around the best way to do this, but none of them worked for me. (Or, probably I don't use the function in the right way.) For example,

```
output= (df1!=df2)
```

This returns,

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

So, it does not take into account score column.

What I expect is to get,

```
name, score
Jane, 98
Anny, 81
```

Jane and Anny are not in the df2.

How can I do this?

Comment: `df1[~df1.name.isin(df2.name)]`

Comment: Thanks, Andy. But, I got an error as,

'AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: @Andy beat me to the answer. If you get an AttributeError, your column names are not what you described in the question.

Comment: @K.K.: I turn to answer to provide the fix. check my answer

Answer (score 0):

First to reproduce your example

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['Tom', 'Jane', 'Anny', 'Chuck'], 'score' : [130, 98, 81, 92]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['Amy', 'Chuck', 'Dave', 'Danny', 'Emma', 'Jack', 'Tom', 'Taro']})
```

You can select certain rows from `df1` based on a condidtion with `df1[condition]`. In your case you want the `df1.name` not to be in `df2.name`. With `.name` you access the underlying array which can be coerced to set operations. You get the names in `df2` with `df1.name.isin(df2.name)`. To invert this expression you need to use the binary invert `~` (because it is boolean indexing).

```
In [23]: df1[~df1.name.isin(df2.name)]
Out[23]: 
   name  score
1  Jane     98
2  Anny     81
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have error: `'AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'`, your column names either has spaces or completely different.
Do this simple fix:

```
df1.columns = ['name', 'score']
df2.columns = ['name']
```

after that. It will work

```
df1[~df1.name.isin(df2.name)]
```

Note: I assume your df1 has 2 columns and df2 has 1 column as you describe.